# Why after the object is reaching to the first waypoint instead moving to the next waypoint it's moving in circles around the current waypoint?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Waypoints : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum WayPointsStateEnum
    {
        Forward, Reverse, Random
    }

    public WayPointsStateEnum waypointState;
    public Transform nextWaypoint;
    public bool random = false;
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public float slowDownSpeed = 1.5f;
    public float rotationSpeed;

    private int targetIndex = 0;
    private Vector3 originalPosition;
    private Animations anims;
    public List<GameObject> waypoints;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        anims = GetComponent<Animations>();
        CloneObjects cloneObjectsInstance = FindObjectOfType<CloneObjects>();
        originalPosition = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (waypoints.Count > 0)
        {
            DrawLinesInScene();
            WayPointsAI();
        }
        else
        {
            var waypointss = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint");
            foreach(var wp in waypointss)
            {
                waypoints.Add(wp);
            }
        }
    }

    private void WayPointsAI()
    {
        if (waypointState == WayPointsStateEnum.Forward)
        {
            if (targetIndex == waypoints.Count)
                targetIndex = 0;
        }
        if (waypointState == WayPointsStateEnum.Reverse)
        {
            if (targetIndex == 0)
                targetIndex = waypoints.Count;
        }

        nextWaypoint = waypoints[targetIndex].transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, nextWaypoint.transform.position);

        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(nextWaypoint.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);

        //move towards the player
        if (distance < 5)
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * slowDownSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (distance < 0.1f)
        {
            if (waypointState == WayPointsStateEnum.Forward)
            {
                targetIndex++;
            }
            if (waypointState == WayPointsStateEnum.Reverse)
            {
                targetIndex--;
            }
        }
    }

    void DrawLinesInScene()
    {
        // draw lines between each checkpoint //
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(waypoints[i].transform.position, waypoints[i + 1].transform.position, Color.blue);
        }

        // draw a line between the original transform start position 
        // and the current transform position //
        Debug.DrawLine(originalPosition, transform.position, Color.red);

        // draw a line between current transform position and the next waypoint target
        // each time reached a waypoint.
        if (nextWaypoint != null)
            Debug.DrawLine(nextWaypoint.transform.position, transform.position, Color.green);
    }

    void AddColliderToWaypoints()
    {
        foreach (GameObject go in waypoints)
        {
            SphereCollider sc = go.AddComponent<SphereCollider>() as SphereCollider;
            sc.isTrigger = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In inspector for example the Move Speed is set to 50 and the Slow Down Speed is set to 1.5 and in the script the distance check for slow down is if the object is less then 5 distance from the waypoint.

If I will reduce in the inspector the Move Speed for example to 5 then it will be working fine but the idea is to be able to change the Move Speed and Slow Down Speed before running the game and while the game is running to values like Move Speed 50 and Slow Down 1.5 or Move Speed 100 and Slow Down 65 but in this cases it will make circles around the waypoint and will not move to the next waypoint/s.

Comment: As a guess: at high speeds it keeps overshooting the waypoint, so it never is close enough to "reach" it. Maybe a speed-dependent distance to check for "reaching the waypoint"?

Comment: Because it never reaches the exact position but overshoots ...  You should rather use `Vector3.MoveTowards` which prevents overshooting .. also it is possible that you are not rotating fast enough -> since you always move `forward` it might happen that you end up in just the circle that matches your rotation speed ;) In general don't multiply by `Time.deltaTime` when using `Lerp` .. rather use a fix factor in this case